# Shiny R observeEvent for selectInput getting triggered at start of Shiny server

Tags: r, shiny

Below is an example Shiny app:

**ui.R**:

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("Test select input event"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput('testSelect', 'Test',choices = c(1,2,3), multiple = FALSE)
    ),
    mainPanel(
    )
  )
))
```

**server.R**:

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  observeEvent(input$testSelect,{ print("I am getting trigerred unnecessarily")})

})
```

When I start this app the console logs immediately show:

> Listening on http://127.0.0.1:5017
>   [1] "I am getting trigerred unnecessarily"

It seems that `observeEvent` on a select input is triggered unnecessarily at the start of the app. Can someone please explain this behaviour?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is an `ignoreInit` parameter in `observeEvent` which takes care of such unwanted triggers. The following code will prevent the message from being shown at startup.

```
library(shiny)

shinyApp(
  selectInput('testSelect', 'Test', choices = c(1, 2, 3)),
  function(input, output, session){
    observeEvent(
      input$testSelect,                                     ## eventExpr
      {print("I am NOT getting trigerred unnecessarily")},  ## handlerExpr
      ignoreInit = TRUE
    )
  }
)
```

The documentation of the parameter (in `?observeEvent`) gives good insights about how `observeEvent` operates at startup.

> **`ignoreInit`**
>
> If `TRUE`, then, when this `observeEvent` is first created/initialized, ignore the `handlerExpr` (the second argument), whether it is otherwise supposed to run or not. The default is `FALSE`. See Details.

The details section clarifies this further.

> **From Details:** By default, `observeEvent` will run right when it is created (except if, at that moment, `eventExpr` evaluates to `NULL` and `ignoreNULL` is `TRUE`)

By the time `observeEvent` is created, `input$testSelect` will have the value `1` and therefore `handlerExpr` (i.e. the `print` command) is triggered unless `ignoreInit` is set to it's non-default value `TRUE`.